# Refreshing a div every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refresh this AnyChart function div every 3 seconds, so that when data is entered using the (hopefully) interactive wordcloud on a wesbite, it refreshes automatcially. My code currently duplicates the div once, 3 seconds after the page loads. Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

  anychart.data.loadGoogleSpreadsheet({
    key: '14jdnD4rzxPdZfLqpeh4gjtoN6ERyZuovBOoFOwuZQAM',
    sheet: '2'
  }, function(data) {

    var chart = anychart.tagCloud();

    // configure a color scale here
    var customColorScale = anychart.scales.linearColor();
    customColorScale.colors(["#FEBF57", "#428A46", "#21C5B4", "#E7438A", "#21295E"]);

    // set the color scale as the color scale of the chart
    chart.colorScale(customColorScale);

    // add a color range
    chart.colorRange().enabled(true);
    chart.normal().fontFamily("Rubik", "sans-serif");

    // set data
    chart.data(data);
    chart.container('wordcloud-container');
    chart.draw();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  function refresh() {
    var div = $('#wordcloud-container'),
      divHtml = div.html();

    div.html(divHtml);
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    refresh()
  }, 3000);
})
```

```html
<h1>TEST WordCloud with colours</h1>
<div id='wordcloud-container'>
```

Comment: You need to basically give the anonymous function you're passing to `anychart.onDocumentReady()` a name and call it in your interval.

Comment: The `refresh()` function reads a div's text, and sets it inside itself. The function works, it's only overwriting a text with itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your `refresh()` function simply gets the existing HTML of the container and then sets that same HTML within the container again, duplicating the content.

To actually refresh the chart you need to call `loadGoogleSpreadsheet()` from within the interval handler.

An important change to make here is to use `setTimeout()` within the chart callback instead of `setInterval()`. The latter can end up queueing requests if the response is slow, which can lead to your site becoming unresponsive due to too many in-progress requests. The `setTimeout()` approach will only start the timer when the previous request was successfully handled.

```js
let loadChartData = () => {  
  console.log('loading data...');
  
  anychart.data.loadGoogleSpreadsheet({
    key: '14jdnD4rzxPdZfLqpeh4gjtoN6ERyZuovBOoFOwuZQAM',
    sheet: '2'
  }, function(data) {
    var chart = anychart.tagCloud();

    // configure a color scale here
    var customColorScale = anychart.scales.linearColor();
    customColorScale.colors(["#FEBF57", "#428A46", "#21C5B4", "#E7438A", "#21295E"]);

    // set the color scale as the color scale of the chart
    chart.colorScale(customColorScale);

    // add a color range
    chart.colorRange().enabled(true);
    chart.normal().fontFamily("Rubik", "sans-serif");

    // set data
    chart.data(data);
    $('#wordcloud-container').empty(); // important change here to stop duplicating the chart
    chart.container('wordcloud-container');
    chart.draw();
    
    setTimeout(loadChartData, 3000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadChartData();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.8.0/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.8.0/css/anychart-ui.min.css" />
<h1>TEST WordCloud with colours</h1>
<div id='wordcloud-container'></div>
```

One big issue to note here is that your approach of AJAX polling is *not at all scalable*. If this is implemented in a production system you will most likely hit rate limits on the Google docs API, or even be blocked for a potential DDOS risk.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory, that's worked. Ok, is that because of the frequency of refreshing?

Comment: Slowing the frequency will help alleviate the issue, but not avoid it. If you absolutely need to keep server data and client side UI in sync I'd suggest using WebSockets. However, I'd question whether the tag cloud data is ***really*** going to be changing that frequently. It would make more sense to have an observer-pattern based system where the tag cloud gets updated once when the spreadsheet is updated. This central data can then be cached and read as necessary wherever necessary.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand but probably out my depth just now. It may be better to refresh the browser manually because like you say, it's not like it going to change that frequently.